# Take Twelve to Total Twenty Two

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Without repeating the numbers 1 to 12,

Fill the grid below to total 22 in both directions.

$$\def\X{\smash{\rlap{\Space{7pt}{0px}{0px}\llap{\Huge{\times}}}}}
\Large\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
&&5&\\\hline
\rlap{10}~~~&\X&\X&\\[-2px]\hline
&\X&\X&7~\\[-5px]\hline
&9&&\\[-10pt]\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: I replaced your photographed hand-drawn grid with a typed rendition of the same grid. If you don't like the new version, feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: Thx..looks much better..I am not well versed in math Jax and other computer generated ones..also, I just sketch it in my puzzle book and is easier to take a picture..especially some complex ones

Comment: No problem! :-)

Comment: I replaced your typed rendition of the same grid with a MathJax version that looks much closer to the hand-drawn original. If you don't like the new new version, feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: This looks nice and compact..thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer

> `2  12  5   3`
>   `10  -  -  11`
>   `6   -  -   7`
>   `4   9  8   1`

Explanation

> In the column containing 10 in order to make 22, the remaining three should be such that the sum is even. So we can have 2 odd and 1 even or 3 even numbers.
>  In the rows with 5 and 9 and in the column with 7, in order to make the sum even, we need 3 odd or 1 odd and 2 even numbers. 
>  But we have only 3 odd numbers left.
>  So I decided to place all the three in the right most column. So the left most column should have all even and the sum not exceeding 22.
>  This made me to place 2,4,6 in the left most column.
>  At last the numbers were to be arranged such that the sum is 22

Comment: That's only one of three possibilities, I think. Also, not including explanation let you ninja me by under a minute :-D

Comment: 

Comment: Don't worry, +1. It *is* quicker to make some assumptions than to examine all possibilities exhaustively :-)

Comment: 

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

> There are two possible solutions.

### Preliminary deductions

Left column:

> 22-10=12, so we need three numbers summing to 12, without using 5,7,9,10. Those three numbers must be $1,3,8$ or $2,4,6$.

Bottom row:

> 22-9=13, so we need three numbers summing to 13, without using 5,7,9,10. Those three numbers must be $1,4,8$ or $2,3,8$ or $3,4,6$.

In particular, the numbers

> 11 and 12 cannot appear in the left column or the bottom row. Clearly we can't have both 11 and 12 in one row/column, so one of them must be just left of 5 and the other one just above 7.

### Option 1

Let's assume

> 11 is next to 5 and 12 is above 7.

Top row:

> 22-11-5=6, so the last two numbers must be $2,4$.

Right column:

> 22-12-7=3, so the last two numbers must be $1,2$.

So we have

> `4   11  5   2`
>      `10  X   X  12`
>      `.   X   X   7`
>      `.   9   .   1`

The remaining numbers are

> $3,6,8$, but no two of these sum to 12 (for the bottom row) or 8 (for the left column), so there is **no solution here**.

### Option 2

Let's assume

> 12 is next to 5 and 11 is above 7.

Top row:

> 22-12-5=5, so the last two numbers must be $2,3$ or $1,4$.

Right column:

> 22-11-7=4, so the last two numbers must be $1,3$.

So we have one of the following two possibilities:

> `4   12  5   1`
>      `10  X   X  11`
>      `.   X   X   7`
>      `.   9   .   3`
>
>
>      `2   12  5   3`
>      `10  X   X  11`
>      `.   X   X   7`
>      `.   9   .   1`

The remaining numbers are respectively $2,6,8$ or $4,6,8$, so the complete grid is one of the following two:

> `4   12  5   1`
>      `10  X   X  11`
>      `6   X   X   7`
>      `2   9   8   3`
>
>
>      `2   12  5   3`
>      `10  X   X  11`
>      `6   X   X   7`
>      `4   9   8   1`

Comment: Your option 1 solution doesn't add up to 22 on the top or right.

Comment: @JS1 *Oops!* I got my 1 and 4 muddled up. Fixed, thanks.